# Marketing Cloud sFTP .csv Import is not bringing in all the Contacts into the Data Extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, import

The imported .csv file has 100k contacts but only 60k are being imported, have tried a variety of workarounds with no luck, anyone have a solution? The data extension shows only 60k records vs the 100k in the .csv

Comment: do you have a pk field on the DE, is this a sendable DE, do you have any contact delete process

Comment: Can you make sure that you get the email notification for the import and let us know what it says in there?

Comment: You'd get an Import Results file created in the /Import directory on the Enhanced FTP. In the file, there'd be a row for each record that failed to be imported along with a reason.